# Is there any way to use Jest and jest-dom together without having to transpile?

Tags: javascript, module, jestjs, jest-dom

I want to write a unit test with Jest, with [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) as a mock DOM--without having to transpile.  I was hoping all I had to do was import the jest-dom package with a CommonJS import.  But when I do that, then run my tests (with `npm test`), it still fails with:

`ReferenceError: document is not defined` (full output [here](https://pastebin.com/q5QNgzmG))

Any ideas how to resolve this?  My test file is below.

Thanks.

---

**My Code**

*myApp.test.js*

```
require("@testing-library/jest-dom");
document.createElement("div");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I got it working.  Here were the edits I made:

**`myApp.test.js` (test file)**

`require("@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect");`

I saw there in [this post](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/122).

**`package.json` Add the following to top level:**

```
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom"
  },
```

I did that b/c [this doc page](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/setup) said I should edit my Jest testEnvironment to `jest-environment-jsdom`. I don't know why that string is used as the value, instead of the name of the package (`test-dom`). But this is what's working for me.

[This doc page](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration) shows how to edit my Jest testEnvironment.